# adicionar coluna que mostre quantas vezes um valor ja se repetiu daquela linha pra traz

Tags: r

Estou tendo problemas para criar uma coluna que mostre quantas vezes uma linha já se repetiu, mas não no dataset inteiro, e sim daquela linha pra traz.

Ex:

```
NOME     ANO       MES    COLUNA_QUE_QUERO_CRIAR
A        2016      4          1
A        2016      4          2
B        2016      5          1
B        2016      5          2
B        2016      5          3
```

o que eu consigui fazer é que nessa coluna fica o valor do dataset inteiro. Tipo, pro A fica 2 e 2, pro B 3 3 e 3, mas eu quero essa contagem.

o que fiz que deu esse resultado que não desejo foi

```
dataset %>% group_by(NOME) %>% mutate('COLUNA_QUE_QUERO_CRIAR' = n())
```

Alguem consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Só utilizar a função `seq`

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>% 
  group_by(NOME) %>% 
  mutate(COLUNA_QUE_QUERO_CRIAR = seq(1:n()))
```

Comment: mano, sou mt burro. Eu sabia disso apóskdaposkdoapksdopakdkaopdopakd. Valeu cara!